# How to select specific groups to copy to a user with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When I create a user, I need to copy group membership from another user - but only specific groups.

```
$UserNameToCopyFrom = read-host “Type the UserName to copy groupmembership from“
$UserNameToCopyTo = read-host "Type the UserName to copy groupmembership To“
Get-ADUser -Identity $UserNameToCopyFrom -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |  Add-ADGroupMember -Members $UserNameToCopyTo
Write-Host "The groupsmembership copy to $UserNameToCopyTo Successfully"
```

This script copies all the groups, what I need is to for example to copy all the groups that are in the Accounting OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day Nati

You can try to use the `Out-GridView` option.

```
$user = Read-Host "Type the user to get the groups"
$groups = (Get-ADUser -Identity $user -properties "memberof").memberof | Out-GridView -Outputmode Multiple
```

With this `-OutputMode Multiple` you will be able to select two or more items

I hope you find this usefull

Any question please don't hesitate on ask

EDIT: I simplified the process removing one line

Comment: thank you. but now how do i select the accounting and copy them to the new user?

Comment: When you use the Out-GridView you will have a new Pop-Up window to select the groups

Then as you can see we are using $groups to get the group list
There you can do a Foreach loop like --> foreach ($group in $groups) with the add-ADgroupmember

Comment: Hi Nati, If you question is gone, can you please mark my answer as correct?
Thanks